# How to implement custom validate connections pool with org.apache.commons.pool2 in java

Tags: java, apache, pool

actually I have three indipendent servers and for each server I have to inizialize a connection pool map with three threads to query the archives situated into each server.
For example:

```
server1 --> [connection_sever1_1, connection_sever1_2, connection_sever1_3]
server2 --> [connection_sever2_1,connection_sever2_2,connection_sever2_3]
server3 --> [connection_sever3_1,connection_sever3_2,connection_sever3_3]
```

I place before that used `org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactory`
At the startup the application makes the connection with threads pool configured into `org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig` but is probably that after idle time each server the thread connection are no longer valid. How could I implement a methods to validate if the connection pool is still valid ?

How can I validate all threads of the connection pool of the server ?

Comment: In case of someone needs this answer, it is possible to override the method public boolean validateObject(final K key, final PooledObject<V> p)